# Where can I legally read manga online in Germany?

Tags: resources, germany

Are there any sites like [crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/) that offer lots of manga that are available in Germany? I don't want German translations, but the crunchyroll stuff is mostly not available in Germany and many manga I read aren't available there.

Some mangas I read:

- Aka Akatoretachi no Monogatari
- Akame ga Kiru!
- Ana Satsujin
- Radukai Kishi no Eiyuutan
- Dungeon Ni Deai O Motomeru No Wa Machigatte Iru Darou Ka
- Freezing
- Gokukoku No Brynhildr
- Big Order
- Isekai Maou to Shoukan Shoujo Dorei Majutsu

Comment: Armin, do you care even if it's an app, where you can read manga?

Comment: @user28546 as long as it is an Android app, no.

Comment: The app works for both apple and android

Comment: @user28546 if it is completely legal, then please, post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

All though there are not a lot subscription based sites like [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga), The following sites do offer a broad variety of digital manga editions, which should have a lot less geo limitations. Which streaming sites like Crunchyroll do tend to have

- [Bookwalker](http://global.bookwalker.jp/)
- [Kodanasha](http://kodanshacomics.com/)
- [Comicwalker](http://comic-walker.com/)
- [Viz](http://www.viz.com/)
- [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Manga-Comics-Graphic-Novels-Books/b?ie=UTF8&node=4367)

Considering that [breaking the terms of service](http://gizmodo.com/5901339/its-not-a-crime-to-break-a-terms-of-service-agreement-so-keep-on-not-reading-them) is not necessarily illegal. You could also buy yourself a VPN, and read the manga from a region where it is available, making it a semi-legal solution as well.

Comment: saidly, i can't use crunchyroll, because most mangas i read (well, all to be honest) aren't available there. maybe the animes of them are available there (like shingeki no kyojin) but not the mangas, which i prefer.

Comment: and buying every manga i read is very expensive for a student -.-

Comment: @Armin Not only for students. Manga is expensive, all though digital copies tend to be a quite a bit cheaper then physical ones. By lack of digital/streaming versions, you sadly end up with having to buy them real quickly. If you don't mind physicall copies, you can always see if you can buy them second hand. I sometimes manage to buy several manga's for only .50 cent/a euro a piece.

Comment: FWIW Comicwalker can be used for free, but it has relatively limited titles (although I assume that it also depends on the language you're reading), and possibly only a limited "preview" for what it does have. (I was only able to read the first four EVA chapters in English when I last used the site.)

Comment: @Maroon yeah, I've tried finding some of my mangas, I read there. No luck -.-